# How do I shade between lines with identical "y"s?

Tags: r, ggplot2, area

I´ve spent few hours trying between geom_polygon & geom_ribbon and I just cannot get it to work. I am looking to shade the area between the two lines (I researched it quite a bit).See, both axis of the graph are numeric and the two lines share the same y axis, therefore, I cannot get it to work calculating ymin nor ymax. Any ideas guys? I would totally appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(npsmelt,aes(Score,Unresolved)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=Metric, color=Metric)) +
    theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = element_blank()) +
    geom_point(aes(color=Metric)) +
    theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, margin=margin(t=10))) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(54,70,1)) + 

    geom_ribbon(data=subset(npsmelt, 
         Score[Metric=="Old.NPS"]<Score[Metric=="New.NPS"]),
         aes(ymin =0, ymax =..y..), alpha=0.10)
```

The resulting graph:
[image]

My data:

```
Unresolved  Metric  Score
    5   New.NPS 66.48
    6   New.NPS 65.32
    7   New.NPS 64.16
    8   New.NPS 63
    9   New.NPS 61.84
   10   New.NPS 60.68
    5   Old.NPS 68.5 
    6   Old.NPS 62.28
    7   Old.NPS 61.74
    8   Old.NPS 61.41
    9   Old.NPS 61.67
   10   Old.NPS 60.42
```

`dput`:

```
structure(list(Unresolved = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), Metric = c("New.NPS", "New.NPS", "New.NPS", 
"New.NPS", "New.NPS", "New.NPS", "Old.NPS", "Old.NPS", "Old.NPS", 
"Old.NPS", "Old.NPS", "Old.NPS"), Score = c(66.48, 65.32, 64.16, 
63, 61.84, 60.68, 68.5, 62.28, 61.74, 61.41, 61.67, 60.42)), .Names = c("Unresolved", 
"Metric", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: could you please `dput()` your data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to me one of the rare occasion when is better to have the dataset in a 'wide' format.

I'll use the long format for `geom_line` and `geom_point`, then switch to a wide format for the `geom_ribbon`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ggplot(df, aes(Unresolved, Score, group = Metric, color = Metric)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = spread(df, Metric, Score), 
              aes(x = Unresolved, ymin = New.NPS, ymax = Old.NPS), 
              alpha = .2,
              inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Note the `inherit.aes = FALSE`, it is needed because otherwise `geom_ribbon` will try to use the `Score` column that's mapped to `y`.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Unresolved = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), Metric = c("New.NPS", "New.NPS", "New.NPS", 
"New.NPS", "New.NPS", "New.NPS", "Old.NPS", "Old.NPS", "Old.NPS", 
"Old.NPS", "Old.NPS", "Old.NPS"), Score = c(66.48, 65.32, 64.16, 
63, 61.84, 60.68, 68.5, 62.28, 61.74, 61.41, 61.67, 60.42)), .Names = c("Unresolved", 
"Metric", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, not just because you solved my problem, but for sharing your knowledge about specific parts of the code. I learned something very important.